# Rewriting 2nd parameter in query string

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Like so many I am struggling with what ought to be a simple rewrite

The initial form is something like:

```
http://cassie-family.co.uk/individual.php?pid=I807&ged=Cassy%20Family%20History.ged
```

The last parameter only needs rewriting, as in:

```
http://cassie-family.co.uk/individual.php?pid=I807&ged=Cassie%20-%20Cassy%20Family%20History
```

I have tried to trap the first parameter using:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=([^&]+)    [NC]
```

The nearest (incorrect) RewriteRule is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ individual.php&pid=%1&ged=Cassie%20-%20Cassy%20Family%20History [L, NC, R=301]
```

The moment I try to replace the '&' after individual.php with the correct '?' the URL is written as:

```
http://cassie-family.co.uk/individual.php
```

So.. the parameter is being trapped correctly but the rewrite rule is clearly mangled. The error lies in here:

```
^(.*)$ individual.php&
```

What construct should I be using to replace only the 2nd (passed-in) parameter value (which is always the same fixed string) with a different 2nd value (which is always the same but slightly different fixed string)? Adding a B flag seems to make no difference.

All suggestions welcome,
Thanks,
Ric